# AS3 Finding the most common Value in an Array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

i would like to find a way to find the most common value in an Array, so in the bellow array called "data" it has 10 values of "1". how would i be able to extract this information finding it hard to find any information on this. any help would be appreciated!

```
var data:Array = ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2","one","two","five","six","1","2","one","two","three","four","five","2","one","two","three","four","five","2","five","2","one","two","five","six","2","one","two","five","six","2","one","two","five","six"];

results = "1";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the most efficient way, but it certainly does the trick:

```
function mostCommonValue(array:Array):Object
{
    // create a dictionary of each unique item in the array and its count     
    var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary(true);
    for each(var element:Object in array)
    {
        if(!dict[element]){
            dict[element] = 0;
        }
        dict[element]++;
    }

    var max:Number = 0;
    var mostCommon:Object;
    // loop over each item in the dictionary to find the highest number of occurrences 
    for(var key:Object in dict)
    {
        if(dict[key] > max){
            max = dict[key];
            mostCommon = key;
        }
    }

    return mostCommon;
}
```